# Why there is no indentation when I use clangd in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, clangd

when I type **if** and use clangd code completion, I got this.

```
if (condition) {
statements
}
```

I'm expecting

```
if (condition) {
    statements
}
```

It's the same thing for **while** and **for**.

```
clangd-12 --version
Ubuntu clangd version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4
clangd extension
v0.1.13
```

Although I apt installed clangd-12, vscode clangd extension installed clangd 12.0.1.zip for me automatically.

I guess this has something to do with the problems.

Comment: Are you also using clang-format?

Comment: @sweenish there is no .clang-format in this project

Comment: That wouldn't stop you from using the tool, though. What I'm getting at is that clangd's job is not to format your code. But it is clang-format's.

Comment: I'm not expecting clangd to format the code. It's just so weird that there's no indentation before **statement**.

Comment: That's what formatting is.. At the end of day, it might just be a bug in one of the extension or clangd. With clang-format, it's also just an annoyance. I don't use that extension myself in VS Code. I do use clangd with neovim, but I haven't set up snippets with it. One last thing, did you install the LLVM suite as well? You only indicate that you've installed clangd.